# Laravel database acces denied root

Tags: php, mysql, linux, laravel

i'm tryin to conect my laravel project for the first time with my database mysql but is getting impossible. I have ubuntu 20. Whenever I try to migrate (php artisan migrate) i keep getting this:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = laravel and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:671
    667|         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    668|         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    669|         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    670|         catch (Exception $e) {
  > 671|             throw new QueryException(
    672|                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    673|             );
    674|         }
    675| 

      +34 vendor frames 
  35  artisan:37
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

I tried everything... my .ENV file i believe is correct:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel1
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=1234
```

i have a user "root" and pass "1234". In console it works just fine -> sudo mysql -u root -p (and then 1234)...
I also have created the database laravel1 in phpmyadmin, so that's ok...
help

Answer (score 0):

`sudo mysql -u root -p` here is issue  it should work like `mysql -u root -p`(without sudo)

you can't access your database without root access to solve this i use

- Step 1  `sudo mysql -u root -p` ---- login with this then run cmd
- Step 2 > `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '1234';` ---- here u can change your password anything u want
- Step 3 > `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

it should work